# typescript installing with npm command in ubuntu 15

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, ubuntu-15.04

i have a beginner in UBUNTU and recently start AngularJS2 . when i try to install typescript with following command

```
NPM install -g typescript
```

i receive following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gbtK.png)

Comment: try `sudo npm install -g typescript` ?

Comment: yes and receive following message..http://uupload.ir/files/9o1o_1.png   typescript truly installed?!

Comment: It seems installed?

Comment: try tsc -v. It should work or if not https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using global argument `-g` you need admin permission. So try with this:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```